# Unit test akka actor method

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

I have an actor of the form:

```
class TestActor(repo: Repo) extends Actor {
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = context.dispatcher

  def receive: Receive = {
    ...
  }

  def testMethod(stringSeq: Seq[String]): String =
       ...
    }
}
```

I want to test the method testMethod only.

I am trying to write the test case as:

```
class TestActorSpec
    extends TestKit(ActorSystem("TestActorSpec"))
    with WordSpecLike
    with Matchers
    with JsonSupport
    with MockitoSugar
    with BeforeAndAfterAll
    with ImplicitSender {
  override def afterAll: Unit = TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)

  implicit val futureDuration: FiniteDuration = 60.seconds
  implicit val timeout: Timeout               = 10.seconds
  val mockedRepo               = mock[Repo]

  val testActorRef: ActorRef = system.actorOf(
    TestActor.props(mockedRepo)
  )

  "TestActorSpec" should {
    "be able to get data " in {

    }
  }
}
```

How can i access the method testMethod from testActorRef ?

I also tried:

```
 TestActorRef[TestActor].underlyingActor.testMethod(Seq("data"))
```

It does not work for me.

Comment: Although you might have a valid use case for this, I would say that in general Actors should only have `receive` as the only public method. `testMethod` should be `private`. `receive` will then call your `testMethod`. Your test will invoke the `testMethod` functionality via `receive`.

Comment: It's not directly called from receive but there is a method in receive which calls this method. In future will take that method out in utils  but for now i only want to test this method. Is there any way? @krismath

Comment: I think private methods can also be tested using power mockito but not sure

Comment: Yeah, my point wasn't about whether private methods can be tested, but that methods should be tested via its interface / contract. Generally speaking, actors will only have `receive` as its only contract which is called via receive. Per my understanding, actors are designed to be called only via 'telling'. If you are going to test something else, may I suggest that you instantiate `TestActor` without using an `ActorSystem`?

Answer (score 3):

Actors should be tested via messages you send to them. But you still can test methods in isolation if the method is not accessing any actor specific values, like `context`.

You can move `testMethod` into companion object and test it from there.

```scala
class TestActor(repo: Repo) extends Actor {
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = context.dispatcher

  def receive: Receive = {
//    call  TestActor.testMethod
  }

}

object TestActor {
  def testMethod(stringSeq: Seq[String]): String = ???
}
```